# How to create enum object from its type and name of the value?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a type (System.Type) of an enum and a string containing enumeration value to set.

E.g. given:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C };
```

I have typeof(MyEnum) and "B".

How do I create MyEnum object set to MyEnum.B?

Answer (score 16):

```
MyEnum enumValue = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "B");
```

You also have a case-insensitive overload.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you don't have access to MyEnum, only to typeof(MyEnum):

```
void foo(Type t)
{
   Object o = Enum.Parse(t, "B");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with generics. I created a Utility class to wrap this:

```
public static class Utils {
    public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value) {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
    }
```

Then invoked like:

```
string s = "B";
MyEnum enumValue = Utils.ParseEnum<MyEnum>(s);
```