# how to get value of an unknown enum by name of enum and name of value?

Tags: c#, enums

sorry for asking this question but i didn't found the right solution for this task:

I've got a Enum, which is named "myEnum" (MyEnum isn't known by the function)
I Need to get the int value of a Value of myEnum

Example:
A Programmer named its enum "myEnum":

```
 public enum myEnum
 {
     foo = 1,
     bar = 2,
 }
```

my function should do the following:
     Get the Value of "foo" of "myEnum" by string

function should opened by:

```
 public int GetValueOf(string EnumName, string EnumConst)
 {

 }
```

so when Programmer A opens it by :

```
 int a = GetValueOf("myEnum","foo");
```

it should return 1

and when Programmer B has an Enum named "mySpace", wants to return "bar" with Value 5

```
int a = GetValueOf("mySpace","bar")
```

should return 5

how can i do this?

Comment: What is the use case? What actual, real scenario are you trying to solve?

Comment: The guts of this are the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169116/how-to-create-enum-object-from-its-type-and-name-of-the-value?rq=1

Comment: @Oded: The use case: I Want a Library where you can specify your own Enumerator for an ArrayList, so that the Programmer can Grab Value from ArrayList by its Name, the Enumerations inside gets a ReadableName with its Value of the ArrayList (eg.: Foo = 1, Bar = 2, Name = 3, Cost = 4 etc.)

Comment: @DanielAlexanderKarr Why not just use a `Dictionary` with the enum as the key?

Comment: can you give me an example with Dictionary in Use?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to do this, but you'd need the fully qualified type name of the Enum type, ie: `"SomeNamespace.myEnum"`:

```
public static int GetValueOf(string enumName, string enumConst)
{
    Type enumType = Type.GetType(enumName);
    if (enumType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Specified enum type could not be found", "enumName");
    }

    object value = Enum.Parse(enumType, enumConst);
    return Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```

Also note that this uses `Convert.ToInt32` instead of a cast.  This will handle enum values with underlying types which are not `Int32`.  This will still throw an `OverflowException`, however, if your enum has an underlying value outside of the range of an `Int32` (ie: if it's a ulong as the value is >`int.MaxValue`).

Comment: Thanks for it, will try it shortly. Is there a possibility to get the fully qualified type name like: GetValueOf(MyEnum.Domain + "." MyEnum.Name, MyEnum.Const.ToString()) ?         To Help you Understand: I will write a Library with a function to iterate through an Array by given Enum and its Value by Int to get the Value of this Array

Comment: Thank you, that worked, now (i dont want to open another thread for it) i only need the Maximum Amount of Enumentries like:    "public enum Foo { a=1, b=2, c=5, }  --> response should be 3 (because there are 3 entries inside enum) and another function to get the maximumvalue inside the enum like:    "public enum Foo { a=1, b=2, c=5 } --> response should be 5

Comment: One critically important question do i still have: my project got the namespace "Cache", how do i get the enum "MyEnum" of namespace "MyProject" ? "Cache.MyEnum" works pretty well mate ;)

Comment: @DanielAlexanderKarr That should be a separate question - but you can use Enum.GetNames and Enum.GetValues to get the names + values.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx  and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Please try

```
int result = (int) Enum.Parse(Type.GetType(EnumName), EnumConst);
```

Comment: Note that this will work most of the time, but throw if the enum's underlying type is not `Int32`.

Comment: Although this is a quick solution, Enum.GetValues and Enum.GetNames are not implemented in the .NET Compact Framework (just for the OP to be aware)

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, good comment. To fix you may use Convert.ToInt32 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're trying to instance the enum from the string value (it's name) then I'll suggest you to [get it members via reflection](http://www.distribucon.com/blog/GettingMembersOfAnEnumViaReflection.aspx) and then compare.

Please be aware reflection [adds a bit of overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224245/744484).

Comment: @AlbertoLeón why is it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me if the name of the enum type must be specified as a string.

You need to use Enum.TryParse to get the value of the Enum.  In combination with a generic method, you could do something like this:

```
public int? GetValueOf<T>(string EnumConst) where T : struct
{
    int? result = null;

    T temp = default(T);
    if (Enum.TryParse<T>(EnumConst, out temp))
    {
        result = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
    }

    return result;
}
```

To call it use this:

```
int? result = GetValueOf<myEnum>("bar");
if (result.HasValue)
{
    //work with value here.
}
```